How can I reuse a function between multiple targets (e.g., JVM and Android)?
I have following use cases that I can't solve without repetitive code.
I want to use the same implementation of a function for the JVM and Android target and provide another implementation for iOS only.
Sadly in this case I have to copy the code between JVM and Android.
Example
// expect function
expect fun defaultFormatterWeekDayLabel(dayOfWeek: DayOfWeek): String

// implementation - native
actual fun defaultFormatterWeekDayLabel(dayOfWeek: DayOfWeek): String {
    return dayOfWeek.name
}

// implementation - android + jvm
actual fun defaultFormatterWeekDayLabel(dayOfWeek: DayOfWeek): String {
    // android and jvm offer access to localised names
    return dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(
        TextStyle.SHORT,
        Locale.getDefault()
    )
}

Sadly I can't reuse the code between Android and JVM - or can I somehow? I have to copy the implementation in this case.

Did you see this article about code sharing between JVM and Android? https://chetan-garg36.medium.com/kotlin-multiplatform-sharing-code-between-android-and-jvm-targets-091c4ab3838c

@DavidWasser I can't read that currently but the comment has a suggestion that I will try, thanks.

You should be able to create an intermediate source set (e.g. javaMain) in your build.gradle file, and let your androidMain and jvmMain source sets depend on javaMain. Then just have separate actual functions per source set.

Here's my final solution for such a use case:
sourceSets {

    // -------------------------
    // create a custom sourceSet
    // -------------------------
    
    val notJvmMain by creating {
        dependsOn(commonMain.get())
    }
    
    // -------------------------
    // define your normal dependencies as always...
    // -------------------------
    
    commonMain.dependencies {
    }
    androidMain.dependencies {
    }
    jvmMain.dependencies {
    }
    jsMain.dependencies {
    }
    wasmJsMain.dependencies {
    }
    
    // -------------------------
    // link your custom source sets with the existing source sets
    // -------------------------
    
    androidMain.get().dependsOn(notJvmMain)
    jsMain.get().dependsOn(notJvmMain)
    wasmJsMain.get().dependsOn(notJvmMain)
    // androidMain and jvmMain DO NOT depend on notJvmMain in my case
}

